# Change the text "Background location is on on the keep app up-tp-date." in carp_background_location

Tags: flutter

How can I change change the text "Background location  is on on the keep the app up-tp-date  with your location . This is requiered for main features to work properly when the app is not running." in carp_background_location: ^ 2.0.0 flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xk3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example app at

- https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location/example

the text is set like this:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Subscribe to stream in case it is already running
    LocationManager().interval = 1;
    LocationManager().distanceFilter = 0;
    LocationManager().notificationTitle = 'CARP Location Example';
    LocationManager().notificationMsg = 'CARP is tracking your location';
    locationStream = LocationManager().locationStream;
    locationSubscription = locationStream.listen(onData);
  }
```

Doesn't this work?

Comment: If we add notificationMsg, it still show the default one.